# Algorithm for finding the set of systems of distinct representatives

Tags: algorithms, sets

Given a collection of finite sets, is there an algorithm for finding the set (unordered) of all systems of distinct representatives for the collection?

Example:

S: {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}

Unordered SDRs: {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}

Notice that {2, 1} is already counted by "{1, 2}" as the SDRs are unordered.

System of Distinct Representatives Definition:

Let S=(S1,S2,...,Sn) be a collection of sets. A System of Distinct Representatives (SDR) of S is a collection of elements x1,x2,...,xn such that xi∈Si and xi≠xj for all i,j∈{1,2,...,n} where i≠j

Please note that, I've asked a [similar question on math exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3528391/the-set-of-systems-of-distinct-representatives-in-a-finite-universe) and am now looking to solve the problem algorithmically.

Any help would be much appreciated.